# Multiple ShareThis Implementations on a Page

Tags: javascript, sharethis

I have a page with different pricing plans and I want each plan column to have it's own ShareThis information.

Here's the markup for email only (I also have Facebook and Twitter):

```
<span class="st_email" st_title="column 1"
                       st_url="http://domain/col1" 
                       displayText=""
                       st_summary="c1 text"></span>

<span class="st_email" st_title="column 2"
                       st_url="http://domain/col2" 
                       displayText=""
                       st_summary="c1 text"></span>

<span class="st_email" st_title="column 3"
                       st_url="http://domain/col3" 
                       displayText=""
                       st_summary="c1 text"></span>
```

The problem is after you click on one column, regardless of whether or not you click on a diff column in the future, you only see the sharethis content for the first column you picked.

I'm sure this has something to do with the ShareThis JS. How do I fix this so that I can have multiple ShareThis links on the same page?