# Sharethis Buttons for Dynamic Pages (Page 2, 3, 4 etc.)

Tags: javascript, html, sharethis

I am using this Social Sharing tool called "Sharethis".
I gives you some header J.S. links to add to your HTML header.

Then, you'll need to add some SPAN in your code to add the social buttons, like this:

```
<span class='st_fblike_hcount' displayText='Facebook Like'></span>
```

Then, on load, you'll see your buttons to click on and get some social activity feedback.
Look at my page, if you have no idea how it looks like:  http://www.seoroger.com/seo_quotes_archive.php

Problem is, I make dynamic pages like: /seo_quotes_archive.php?page=2, page=3, etc.
And this widget considers each of these pages a separate one (which is true somehow), and keeps each page's statistics separately.

I think the right thing to do for this instance, is to have one account for all of these pages and if the user clicks on facebook button on /seo_quotes_archive.php?page=5, for example, it increments the general facebook count.

If you agree, and you know how this is feasible, please help!
Thanks in advance!

PS. This case is the opposite of [Multiple Sharethis buttons per page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644693/multiple-sharethis-implementations-on-a-page). In Fact, it's looking for a way to have one Sharethis statistics for Multiple pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a "st_url" Parameter to specify the shared url. Insert the current url without the page-parameter to share the same url across multiple pages.

```
<span class='st_fblike_hcount' st_url='http://www.example.com/seo_quotes_archive.php' displayText='Facebook Like'></span>
```

Source: http://support.sharethis.com/customer/portal/articles/475079-share-properties-and-sharing-custom-information#sthash.EoamLhNZ.dpbs

Comment: Short and sweet!
Works fine, just like a rel=canonical.
But my question is, this way we can fool the readers by assigning the data of a socially-popular page to a weak page!